# Truncating a JSONArray in java json simple

Tags: java, list, json-simple

Let's say I have a `JSONArray` called `table` in json-simple-1.1.1. I want to truncate it to a maximum number of values. To do so, I take a sub-set and reassign it like so:

```
List<Object> rows = this.table.subList(0, newSize);
table.clear();
table.addAll(rows);
```

However, doing this results in a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on the `table.addAll(rows)` line. The kicker is, that there is only one thread. From reading about the exception on Oracle, it's evident that I'm doing some kind of invalid operation here, but I'm not sure what.

Here's code that will produce the error:

```
package recordIndexer.server.importer;

import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray j = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse("[\"Hello\", \"world\"]");
        List<Object> sub = j.subList(0, 1);
        j.clear();
        j.addAll(sub);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing table.clear() and then table.add()? Just create a new JSONArray and add your rows to it.

Comment: Read carefully the description of `subList`.  It doesn't create a new list but just uses existing list with pointers to the start and end points.  If the source list for the `subList` is modified the `subList` becomes invalid.

Comment: I didn't want to delete object unless I absolutely had to. Modifying seemed like a better path. However, if that won't work, I'll create a new List.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. Your explanation clears it up.